# How can you have two banner ads on one page?

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to have two banner ads on the same page through admob in android studio. I have one ad working, but I am not sure how to get the other working.

So far this is what I have for one ad in java:

```
     AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

This works, but how would I add a second ad with the ID adView2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Showing two ads on the same screen at the same time is actually a violation of AdMob's policies, and could result in the suspension of your account. I would not recommend implementing an app that way.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out now. If anyone needs help this is the code:

```
     // Ad #1 (ID is adView)
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);


    // Ad #2 (ID is adView2)
    AdView adView2 = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView2);
    AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
    adView2.loadAd(adRequest2);
```

Comment: To be clear, showing 2 banner ads on the same page at the same time is a violation of Admob policy and will likely get your account banned.

Comment: @William can you please attach anything from official documentation to endorse your statement?

Comment: @SaddaHussain this has been Admob policy since circa 2010. I couldn't find it in a quick look through their policy page https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287, but this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47698513/493682 is from one of the Admob developer relations team.