# Can we able to display multiple ads in same screen using AdMob

Tags: android, admob

I have one app in which I want to display multiple ads in same screen.

App has one recycler view & which is scrollable more than 200 items. After in each 6 items, I have planed display the ads from admob. Are we able to do this using `admob`.?

I have tried with single ad unit id, with this all displaying ads are same.
How to get different ads in same screen with more secure way & without violating policies ?

Please help!!

Comment: adding multiple ads view is directly violating google policies.

Comment: @Mohammadnabil So at most we can able to display one ad in one screen right ?

Comment: Yes we can show one AdView in one Activity

Answer (score 4):

You can have more than one ad in the same Activity, but only one should be on the screen at any given time. If you're using a RecyclerView and mixing ads with content, just make sure you have enough space between ads that they don't share the screen.

Because display sizes vary so much from device to device (especially from phone to tablet), you should check the device dimensions and use them to decide how far apart to space your ads.

Comment: So having multiple banner ads in same screen not leading to violating google policies.. ?

Comment: Test ads are coming in my recycler view, I have used only one ad unit id to display for all ads in same screen. I have used the view, is PublisherAdView & request is PublisherAdRequest. While building request I have added the device id also
`new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("A53A615B48EFC58B2DF2C6F1F0B046EA").build();`

But I am getting same test ads in all places of recycler view. Is that correct way to use same ad unit id in same screen? Or is there any alternate solution for getting different ads in same screen ?

Comment: There is not a way to guarantee that multiple ads loaded from a single ad unit ID are unique, unfortunately. If you'd like, bring this and your other questions to the AdMob SDK forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-admob-ads-sdk, where the support team can dig in and help you.

Comment: of course, I ll add one questions on above said forum.!
However, currently I need a solution for adding multiple ads(Banner) in recycler view without violating policies.

Can we create more than one ad unit for displaying banner ads in recycler view?, so that while requesting we can use those ad unit. So requesting with multiple ad unit will give different ads right?. Is that good way for implementation?

Comment: @RedBrogdon What if an ad is overlapped by ex. a sliding up panel, should i call destroy on this ad and then reload the adrequest again if visible again?